# How to pass a SESSION variable within a loop between PHP pages

Tags: php, arrays, loops, session-variables

I'm trying to pass the variables `$candid` and `$clientid` from active.php to editor.php. This is the code I have so far for active.php:

```
$active_tsquery = db_select("SELECT * FROM timesheets WHERE status=\"cand\" OR status=\"client\" ORDER BY weekending ASC"); 
    echo "<table width=\"90%\">
        <tr>
        <td width=\"20%\">Client Company</td>
        <td width=\"20%\">Candidate</td>
        <td width=\"20%\">Week Ending</td>
        <td width=\"20%\">Action</td>
        </tr>";

    foreach($active_tsquery as $key => $value) {
        $clientid = $value["clientid"];
        $_SESSION['clientid'] = $clientid;
        $weekend = $value["weekending"];
        $clientresult = db_select("SELECT * FROM timesheetlogin WHERE id=\"$clientid\"");
        $candid = $value["candid"];
        $_SESSION['candid'] = $candid;
        $candresult = db_select("SELECT * FROM timesheetlogin WHERE id=\"$candid\"");
        $ts_id = $value["ts_id"];
        $_SESSION['tsid'] = $ts_id;

        foreach ($clientresult as $key => $value) {
            $company = $value["company"];
        }
        foreach ($candresult as $key => $value) {
            $candidate = $value["name"];
        }

        echo "<tr><td class=\"main-text\">$company</td><td class=\"main-text\">
$candidate</td><td class=\"main-text\">$weekend</td><td class=\"main-text\">
<a href=\"editor.php?id=$ts_id\" class=\"main-link\">Edit</a></td><td class=\"main-link\">
<a href=\"deleteconfirm.php?id=$ts_id\" class=\"main-link\">Delete</a></td></tr>";
    }
```

Active.php is working as `<a href=\"editor.php?id=$ts_id\" class=\"main-link\">Edit</a>` is giving the correct urls.

This is the code I have in editor.php:

```
$candid = $_SESSION['candid'];
$clientid = $_SESSION['clientid'];
$candresult = db_select("SELECT * FROM timesheetlogin WHERE id=\"$candid\"");
$clientresult = db_select("SELECT * FROM timesheetlogin WHERE id=\"$clientid\"");
$tsresult = db_select("SELECT * FROM timesheets WHERE candid=\"$candid\"");
var_dump($tsresult);
```

The `var_dump($tsresult);` is an array of 1, returning the last timesheet every time. I'm assuming because the `$candid` is wrong. The foreach loop in active.php has finished and `$candid` is being returned from the last item in the array?

I am using `session_start();` at the top of each file BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each iteration of the foreach loop, you *overwrite* the current value of $_SESSION['candid']. That is why only the last `candid` is appearing in editor.php.

PHP supports arrays in session variables, so if you initialize the array before the foreach loop:

```
$_SESSION['candid'] = array();
```

(or, new style, working from PHP 5.4 onwards)

```
$_SESSION['candid'] = [];
```

and add the `candid` to this array inside the loop:

```
$_SESSION['candid'][] = $candid;
```

you can iterate over the array inside editor.php.

Comment: `$_SESSION['candid'] = [];`

Comment: `array()` works as well, but is perhaps not common practice?

Comment: @MatissTreinis Not everybody is using totally uptodate versions of PHP. I would suggest using both old and new versions in your example as `[]` only works on newer versions of PHP and `array()` is much more **common place**

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly - I grew up with earlier versions of PHP.

Comment: @RiggsFolly this syntax has been around for almost 3 and a half years. You should not only avoid using the old syntax (it's a bad coding style), you should discourage it. [] is de-facto standard nowdays, and supporting a PHP version which is not maintained already for a year now is not something you should do.

Comment: @Glorfindel I figured it was being overwritten but don't fully understand the rest of your answer. If I use `$_SESSION['candid'][] = $candid;` before the foreach loop I get Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: Not before, inside. Replace your existing code line with one given by @Glorfindel. In addition, clear your session - you have something already in session which will cause problems.

Comment: @IanButler that piece of code should be *inside* the loop.

Comment: Okay indise the loop makes more sense - it still gives the fatal error however

Comment: @IanButler could you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Forgot to initialize the array before the foreach loop. The error is gone now.

Comment: @MatissTreinis It is not even deprecated in PHP7 and my guess is it never will be. I think you are being a little pedantic on this one. We have to live in the real world.

Comment: How would I then access this array in editor.php? Using `$candid = $_SESSION['candid'][];` gives Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading

Comment: Use a foreach loop: `foreach ($_SESSION['candid'] as $candid) {`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by adding [] to `$_SESSION['clientid']` like this: `$_SESSION['clientid'][]` which essentially means "append this to the array".